# django storages with S3, give full or relative URL to client?

Tags: django, amazon-s3

My understanding of S3 is

You don't want your client hit your server then hit s3 via urls.py. Your client is better off getting files(images) from s3 directly.
Therefore you will want to return the whole url(image_field.url) rather than relative path(image_field.name or similar) to your client to use.
But then, what if you move from S3 to some other service?

Returning whole URL to client would be an OK practice assuming you might want to switch from amazon S3 to something else later?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`MEDIA_URL` is the `BASE_URL` for all of your uploaded assets. By default, Django stores a relative path of uploaded files in database.

[If using S3](https://github.com/kylemacfarlane/django-cuddlybuddly-storage-s3), `MEDIA_URL` should be set to your bucket URL , e.g. http://yourbucket.s3.amazonaws.com/.

If you move to some other service then, you can change `MEDIA_URL` setting. It should be that simple.